# Status bar color of main activity changes but other activities status bar color remains same

Tags: android, android-actionbar

How do i change my status bar color to black for all activities as this code only changes status bar color of main activity to black and color of status bar in other activities remain grey.

```
<style name="CustomToolbarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">-4dp</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: mainfests:

<application android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

Comment: how and where did you apply this theme?

Comment: Did you get what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the theme which is set in Manifest's  tag is used to set theme of an activity declared which not having any theme.

You should apply your mentioned theme in **Application's** theme attribute in Manifest.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/CustomToolbarStyle">
.....
</application>
```

And this theme will be overriden by the theme which you set in **Activity** tag's theme attribute in Manifest or theme which is set from Activity's layout, again by theme attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define this theme for other activities too in your manifest

```
<activity
android:name=".YourActivityName"
android:theme="@style/CustomToolbarStyle"/>
```

You can set this theme for all the activities in which you want black status bar color
the color responsible for status color is `colorPrimaryDark` defined in your **colors.XML**